# Getting error java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("APP_LOCAL"."PI_ADDRESS"."EMP_ID")

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

Getting error java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400:

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("APP_LOCAL"."PI_ADDRESS"."EMP_ID")

Below is the code :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PI_EMPLOYEE")
@NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Employee e")
@DynamicUpdate(value=true)
@DynamicInsert(value=true)
public class Employee{

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "PI_EMPLOYEE_SEQ", sequenceName = 
 "PI_EMPLOYEE_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PI_EMPLOYEE_SEQ")
@Column(name = "EMP_ID")
private Long employeeId;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "EMP_ID")
@BatchSize(size=5)
private List<Address> addresses;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PI_ADDRESS")
@DynamicUpdate(value=true)
public class Address {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "PI_ADDRESS_SEQ", sequenceName = "PI_ADDRESS_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PI_ADDRESS_SEQ")
@Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
private Long addressId;

@Column(name = "EMP_ID")
private Long employeeId;

}   



 public class EmployeeRepositoryImpl implements EmployeeRepository {
 @Override
 public Employee saveOrUpdate(Employee employee) {
    Employee employeeToSave = employee;
    if (employee == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Employee should not be null");
    }
    try {
        Address address = employee.getAddress();
        employee.setAddress(null);
        employeeToSave = employeeRepository.save(employee);
        if (null != address) {
            setEmployeeID(employeeToSave.getEmployeeId(), address);
            addressRepository.save(address);
            employeeToSave.setAddress(address);
        }
        return employeeToSave;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception occurred while saving Employee", e);
        throw new BaseException(e);
    }

}

private void setEmployeeID(Long employeeId, Object object) {
    try {
        ReflectionUtil.setFieldValue(object, "employeeId", employeeId);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception occured while setting employeeId " + e);
        throw new BaseException(e);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Error is quite obvious, EMP_ID can't be null

Comment: In setEmployeeId method in saveOrUpdate method in EmployeeRepositoryImpl class I am setting empId to address and that's not null.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by putting nullable=false on parent side and putting insertable=false and updatable=false on child side and removing boilerplate code in EmployeeRepositoryImpl to set employeeId on address.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PI_EMPLOYEE")
@NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Employee e")
@DynamicUpdate(value=true)
@DynamicInsert(value=true)
public class Employee{

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "PI_EMPLOYEE_SEQ", sequenceName = 
"PI_EMPLOYEE_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
"PI_EMPLOYEE_SEQ")
 @Column(name = "EMP_ID")
 private Long employeeId;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "EMP_ID",nullable =false)
@BatchSize(size=5)
private List<Address> addresses;

}
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PI_ADDRESS")
@DynamicUpdate(value=true)
public class Address {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "PI_ADDRESS_SEQ", sequenceName = 
"PI_ADDRESS_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
"PI_ADDRESS_SEQ")
@Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID",nullable =false,insertable =false,updatable=false)
private Long addressId;

@Column(name = "EMP_ID")
private Long employeeId;

 }
```